# PHP imprimir nomes em maiúsculo

Tags: php

Sou novato em programação, venho estudando o manual do PHP para melhor compreender o funcionamento da linguagem.

Tenho de fazer o seguinte exercício:
Imprima os nomes dos alunos em maiúsculo por ordem de matrícula.

Esse é meu código:

```
$nome_alunos = array('andre' => 1 , 'paulo' =>5, 'fabio' => 2);
asort($nome_alunos);
strtoupper($nome_alunos);
foreach ($nome_alunos as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key = $value\n";
```

Eu não consigo colocar em maiúsculo os nomes usando `strtoupper()` que estão dentro do array, só consegui colocar em ordem, também li o manual do PHP e não achei uma função que me ajuda-se além da descrita acima. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está a tentar converter o array $nome_alunos, mas deverá converter cada $key dentro do loop

```
<?php
$nome_alunos = array('andre' => 1 , 'paulo' =>5, 'fabio' => 2);
asort($nome_alunos);

foreach ($nome_alunos as $key => $value) {
   $nome_aluno = strtoupper($key);
   echo "$nome_aluno = $value<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação foi de grande ajuda para entender o meu erro.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa usar a função `strtoupper()` em cada valor. Segue abaixo o código para fazer isso.

```
<?php
    $nome_alunos = array('andre' => 1 , 'paulo' =>5, 'fabio' => 2);

    asort($nome_alunos);
    foreach ($nome_alunos as $key => $value)
        echo strtoupper($key)." = $value<br>";
?>
```

Caso queira deixar apenas a primeira letra maiúscula, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
echo ucwords(strtolower($key)). " = value<br>";
```

Comment: Phelipe funcionou certinho, obrigado pela ajuda!.